# Insert data from excel sheet into linked access tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have multiple(About 9) access tables with One to Many and Many to one relationships(All tables are linked someway, There is a master table with has one to many and many to one relationship with all the tables). I want to insert data into three tables from an excel sheet.

Excel sheet provided has data for only three of the linked tables. How can I best approach this? How complicated insert query I am looking at here?

Any suggestions much much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is my table structure:

Subject

```
SubjectID   (Autonumber)    Primary Key
MasterID    (Number)        Foreign Key
Description (Text)
```

Master

```
MasterID    (Autonumber)    Primary Key
StatusID    (Number)        Foreign Key
StudentID   (Text) 
Description (Text)
```

Status

```
StatusID    (Autonumber)    Primary Key
Description (Text)
```

Table Relationships:

```
Master (One) --> (Many) Subject
Status (One) --> (Many) Master
```

Data from Excel:

```
StudentID Subject    Status
JP121     Math       Active
SP223     Bio        Active
JK111     Chem       In Suspense
LS433     Bio        In Active
NP833     Math       In Active
SS777     Chem       Active
BK299     Bio        In Suspense
```

Comment: Well if you are trying with a single query it can get pretty complex. But if you are ready to break it down to simple small queries, we can have a less complex solution. Overall without looking at schema and excel data its difficult to assist you in the solution.

Comment: @TravisG I am definitely ready to break it down into simple small queries. How should I execute those small queries? I mean in what sequence?

Comment: I would suggest going for the master table first. As the master table would touch all 9, it would be easier for you to build those tables once master is ready. Another approach that you can take is XLS(macro) - > CSV and then CSV -> ACCESS.

Comment: @TravisG Inserting data into master through query inserts one record as many times as it has relationships with others. So one row will be inserted 9 times in master table.

Comment: @HansUp Yes, I have updated my question above. I have simplified it with just a few tables and some data from excel

Comment: @TravisG I have updated my question above with relationships and data from excel. I have simplified it with just a few tables and some data from excel

Comment: Where are those Excel `StudentID` values stored?  Or do you ignore them instead of store them?

Comment: You need to have the `studentID` too. is it in one of the Tables in remaining 6?

Comment: @HansUp In the Master Table, Sorry Missed it somehow.

Comment: Havea look at the old Erlandsen [website](http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacexportado).

Comment: @TravisG Its in Master Table, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I can't understand what you're doing.  Seems to me you could import those 3 Excel columns into a single Access table.

Comment: @HansUp I already have the Access tables with data in it. But, I received this excel sheet with flattened data which I need to insert into these linked tables. Its not just three excel columns, Its many many more. I simplified it so that I can explain better.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on yout table structure, this the process i would recommend

1.) Build `Status` table by selecting all Unique `STATUS` from Excel.

2.) Build the `Subject` Table by selecting all Unique `Subjects` from Excel.

3.) Once these tables are populated, you can proceed to build your master table. For every `student` row  in the excel, fetch the `statusID` from `status` table and `subjectID` from `subject` table

Does this make sense?

Regarding `Status` table  My understanding is that you intend to populate `Status ID` something like this

```
StatusID | Description
---------|------------
   1     | Active
   2     | InActive
   3     | In Suspense
```

also to add, `Subject` table does not require `MasterID` column. Instead you can have `SubjectID` column in `Master` table

Comment: Kind of. So, I should write an insert query to update Unique data into tables with have foreign key relationship with the master and then update the master table? Your third point does make sense, but how will I fetch the ID's? will I do this in my insert query with I update Master table? Also, Like I said earlier, Updating Master table with insert statement inserted multiple records for each row in excel. It seems like it inserts as many rows as it has relationships. So First row in excel was inserted 9 times and so on with the remaining.

Comment: Yes, Status table is populated that way. Subject table in the same way as well. I cannot update any table structured right now. I already have these Access tables with data in it. Now, I received an excel sheet with flattened data which I need to insert into these linked tables. Its not just three excel columns and three tables, Its many many more. I simplified it so that I can explain better.